# How to convert concurentHashMap into Guava Cache <Key, Pair>

Tags: java, guava

Let say that we have a method that returns ConcurentMap with pairs <String, String> for old and new values of numbers.

```
public ConcurrentMap<String, String> getAllOldAndNewPairs() {
        return databaseConnector.executeQuery(QUERY, new QueryLauncher<ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>>() {

            @Override
            public ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> processResult(Results results) throws DAOException {

                ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> oldAndNewPairs = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
                while (results.next()) {
                    oldAndNewPairs.put(results.getString(Column.OLD_NUMBER), results.getString(Column.NEW_NUMBER));
                }
                return oldAndNewPairs;
            }
        });
    }
```

I want to fill the guava cache with <Key, Pair> record from method `getAllOldAndNewPairs()`

So far I have a method like:

```
    public void propagateCache() {

        LoadingCache<String, String> loadingCache =
                CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String load(String s) throws Exception {
                        return getAllOldAndNewPairs();
                    }
                });
    }
```

but currently IDE complaining about line:

```
return getAllOldAndNewPairs();
```

> Required Type: String - Provided: Concurrent Map<String, String>

I was trying either:

```
    LoadingCache<String, String> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .build(CacheLoader.from(this::getAllOldAndNewPairs));
```

and either this did not bring a desirable effect.

I will be grateful for suggestions on how to solve this problem and fill the cache with <Key, Pair> values from method getAllOldAndNewPairs.

Comment: You say you want to "fill the cache": are you talking about pre-loading some existsing value into the cache or do you want each individual cache miss to look up a value from that map as the computation?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I want to take every single pair from method getAllOldAndNewPairs() and put it(pre-load) directly to the guava cache.

Comment: in that case you use the wrong methods. `CacheLoader` is about the other part: computing missing entries when requested.  Simply calling `putAll()` should do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any guava cache implementation can be populated via map. The following method is part of Guava Cache Interface:

```
void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> var1);
```

That being said, you are incorrectly using LoadingCache. When the key is not present in the cache, cache loader provides the logic to determine the *value* corresponding to the *key*. Hence the cache loader returns value object (String in your case).

Comment: Something the easiest solution is the best, my fault, I completely didn't realize that this trivial method will handle it. Thanks a lot!